# Show unchecked checkbox(s) with a different color in mailto

Tags: html, forms, checkbox, mailto

I'm doing a form that is supposed to send its answers to an email.
It does send the checked answers, but i would like to have the unchecked answers in red for example in order to show what's checked and what's not in the mail.

```
<form action="mailto:myadress@gmail.com?subject=New mail" name="email" method=POST enctype="text/plain">
<input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check1" value="Check_1">
<label for="coding">Check 1</label>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check2" value="Check_2">
<label for="coding">Check 2</label>
<br/>
<input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="check3" value="Check_3">
<label for="coding">Check 3</label>
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

If someones could help me with this problem,

Thank you

For example, the mail would be

check1=Check_1

**check2=Check_2**

**check3=Check_3**

with red font instead of black

Comment: You can't do that via HTML alone. Your current approach will simply dump the form data in the e-mail body. You'll need to construct the e-mail as HTML, probably via a submit event in JavaScript then a `location.href = 'mailto:...'`.

Comment: @Utkanos — That won't work. The `mailto:` URL scheme doesn't allow for colour formatting.

Comment: Oh, fair enough - I had assumed there was a means to pass HTML to `&body=...`.

Answer (score 0):

Forms using the `mailto:` URI scheme, aside from [being highly unreliable](http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html), do not have any way to suggest formatting styles in the resulting email.

The only way to do this would be to switch to an HTTP(S) action and generate the email with server-side code.